# Rendering video from Photoshop CS6 leaves background grey where it should be white

Tags: video, animation-rendering

On export of an animation from Photoshop, the rendered video has a grey background where it should be white.

We have tried multiple settings and documents and nothing we've tried works.

[These are the exact setting we are using](https://www.inkling.com/read/photoshop-cs6-missing-manual-lesa-snider-1st/chapter-20/exporting-videos). And also tried numerous other options.

Does anyone know what might cause this? Using CS6. Thanks.

We have now tried every conceivable solution and not found it. Oddly enough, when we play the video in Windows Media Player it is perfect but not in VLC. Also, uploaded the video to YouTube

and in the player it is grey but when you open it in the Video Manager, it is white.

It also appears as white in Google+, Facebook and anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably worth checking your Image>Mode settings.
I find they tend to change my colours between exports and prints etc.